# HTML email template Background Color issue in Outlook

Tags: html, css, html-table, outlook, html-email

My HTML-Email template background color is not rendering properly in Outlook.

I have used different techniques but still not working.

I have wrapped the whole section into a table and applied background color to `#ececec` and applied color to inner `td` background to #ffffff but still whole outer table background color is `#ffffff` I want the outer table background color to be `#ececec` as shown in `Gmail view`.

Gmail view:

[image]

Outlook desktop view:

[image]

How to make it same looking as in Gmail?

Here is my code

```
<table bgcolor="#ececec" align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width:100%; border-collapse: collapse;">
  <tr>
      <td bgcolor="#ffffff"  style="text-align: justify;width: 50%;">
        <table bgcolor="#ffffff" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
              <tr>
                  <td bgcolor="#ffffff" style="padding-left: 30px; padding-right: 10px; ">
                      <img width="40" height="40" alt="" src="https://www.example.com/pub/media/wysiwyg/icons/icon-number1.png" style="vertical-align: middle; display: inline-block; width: 40px; height: 40px;">
                  </td>
                  <td bgcolor="#ffffff" style="width: 74%; padding-top: 20px;padding-bottom: 20px;">
                      <div style="vertical-align: middle; display: inline-block;">
                          <h3 style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">Australia's No. 1</h3>
                          <span>Replica lighting store</span>
                      </div>
                  </td>
              </tr>
          </table>              
      </td>
      <td bgcolor="#ffffff"  style="text-align: justify;width: 50%;">
        <table bgcolor="#ffffff" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
              <tr>
                <td bgcolor="#ffffff" style="padding-left: 30px; padding-right: 10px;  ">
                      <img width="40" height="40" alt="" src="https://www.example.com/pub/media/wysiwyg/icons/icon-huge-range.png" style="vertical-align: middle; display: inline-block; width: 40px; height: 40px;">
                  </td>
                  <td  bgcolor="#ffffff" style="width: 74%; padding-top: 20px;padding-bottom: 20px; ">
                      <div style="vertical-align: middle; display: inline-block; ">
                          <h3 style="margin:0; padding:0;">Huge range</h3>
                          <span>20,000+ products</span>
                      </div>
                  </td>
              </tr>
          </table>
      </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="#ffffff"  style="text-align: justify;width: 50%;">
        <table bgcolor="#ffffff" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
              <tr>
                <td bgcolor="#ffffff" style="padding-left: 30px; padding-right: 10px;">
                      <img width="40" height="40" alt="" src="https://www.example.com/pub/media/wysiwyg/icons/icon-fast-shipping.png" style="vertical-align: middle; display: inline-block; width: 40px; height: 40px;">
                  </td>
                  <td bgcolor="#ffffff" style="width: 74%; padding-top: 20px;padding-bottom: 20px;">
                      <div style="vertical-align: middle; display: inline-block;  ">
                          <h3 style="margin:0; padding:0;">Fast shipping</h3>
                          <span>24hr dispatch on most items</span>
                      </div>
                  </td>
              </tr>
          </table>
      </td>
      <td bgcolor="#ffffff"  style="text-align: justify;width: 50%;">
            <table bgcolor="#ffffff" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
              <tr>
                <td bgcolor="#ffffff" style="padding-left: 30px; padding-right: 10px; ">
                      <img width="40" height="40" alt="" src="https://www.example.com/pub/media/wysiwyg/icons/icon-30-days.png" style="vertical-align: middle; display: inline-block; width: 40px; height: 40px;">
                  </td>
                  <td bgcolor="#ffffff" style="width: 74%; padding-top: 20px;padding-bottom: 20px;">
                      <div style="vertical-align: middle; display: inline-block; ">
                          <h3 style="margin:0; padding:0;">30 days returns</h3>
                          <span>For peace of mind</span>
                      </div>
                  </td>
              </tr>
          </table>
      </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Try to use the `bgcolor` instead of `background-color` for `td` elements.

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev I have changed code and added `bgcolor` as `td` attribute See my updated question but still same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to do too much with one table. You have the `table` background set to light grey and its `<td>`s set to a white background. That will give you a white table that spans 100% of the viewport. You won't even see the light gray. The `td`s make up the table.

Try nesting more tables to pull this off.  Consider this simplified structure.

```html
<!-- body background -->
<table width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="#ececec" style="padding: 20px 0 20px 0;">
      
      <!-- container background-->
      <table width="500" align="center">
        <tr>
          <td bgcolor="#ffffff" style="padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;">
            
            <!-- content -->
            <table width="100%">
              <tr>
                <td>This content has a white background. No need to set a background color for every td.</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>This content has a white background too, just to be clear.</td>
              </tr>
            </table>

          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>

    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Again, this HTML is simplified to demonstrate a sturdy way to have a container of one background color exist in front of another background color.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest checking out this article about outlook's css quirks: **[A Guide to Rendering Differences in Microsoft Outlook Clients](https://www.litmus.com/blog/a-guide-to-rendering-differences-in-microsoft-outlook-clients)**. It talks about using VML as a workaround.

Issue:

```
<!--[if mso]>
<table align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width:100%; border-collapse: collapse;">
<tr>
<td style="background-color:#ececec;">
<![endif]-->
<table bgcolor="#ececec" align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width:100%; border-collapse: collapse;">
       <tr>
    <td bgcolor="#ffffff"  style="text-align: justify;width: 50%;">
      <table bgcolor="#ffffff" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
            <tr>
                <td bgcolor="#ffffff" style="padding-left: 30px; padding-right: 10px; ">
                    <img width="40" height="40" alt="" src="https://www.example.com/pub/media/wysiwyg/icons/icon-number1.png" style="vertical-align: middle; display: inline-block; width: 40px; height: 40px;">
                </td>
                <td bgcolor="#ffffff" style="width: 74%; padding-top: 20px;padding-bottom: 20px;">
                    <div style="vertical-align: middle; display: inline-block;">
                        <h3 style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">Australia's No. 1</h3>
                        <span>Replica lighting store</span>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>              
    </td>
    <td bgcolor="#ffffff"  style="text-align: justify;width: 50%;">
      <table bgcolor="#ffffff" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
            <tr>
              <td bgcolor="#ffffff" style="padding-left: 30px; padding-right: 10px;  ">
                    <img width="40" height="40" alt="" src="https://www.example.com/pub/media/wysiwyg/icons/icon-huge-range.png" style="vertical-align: middle; display: inline-block; width: 40px; height: 40px;">
                </td>
                <td  bgcolor="#ffffff" style="width: 74%; padding-top: 20px;padding-bottom: 20px; ">
                    <div style="vertical-align: middle; display: inline-block; ">
                        <h3 style="margin:0; padding:0;">Huge range</h3>
                        <span>20,000+ products</span>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td bgcolor="#ffffff"  style="text-align: justify;width: 50%;">
      <table bgcolor="#ffffff" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
            <tr>
              <td bgcolor="#ffffff" style="padding-left: 30px; padding-right: 10px;">
                    <img width="40" height="40" alt="" src="https://www.example.com/pub/media/wysiwyg/icons/icon-fast-shipping.png" style="vertical-align: middle; display: inline-block; width: 40px; height: 40px;">
                </td>
                <td bgcolor="#ffffff" style="width: 74%; padding-top: 20px;padding-bottom: 20px;">
                    <div style="vertical-align: middle; display: inline-block;  ">
                        <h3 style="margin:0; padding:0;">Fast shipping</h3>
                        <span>24hr dispatch on most items</span>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
    <td bgcolor="#ffffff"  style="text-align: justify;width: 50%;">
          <table bgcolor="#ffffff" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
            <tr>
              <td bgcolor="#ffffff" style="padding-left: 30px; padding-right: 10px; ">
                    <img width="40" height="40" alt="" src="https://www.example.com/pub/media/wysiwyg/icons/icon-30-days.png" style="vertical-align: middle; display: inline-block; width: 40px; height: 40px;">
                </td>
                <td bgcolor="#ffffff" style="width: 74%; padding-top: 20px;padding-bottom: 20px;">
                    <div style="vertical-align: middle; display: inline-block; ">
                        <h3 style="margin:0; padding:0;">30 days returns</h3>
                        <span>For peace of mind</span>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
<!--[if mso]>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: still not solved it looks same in outlook as it was before